# Power of $a^{\dagger}=\sqrt{\frac{\omega m }{2 \hbar}}\left (x-\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\frac{d}{dx} \right)$

Tags: operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics, adjoint-operators

I don't know if a mathematical passage is correct. For the moment I am not entirely interested in formally understanding justification, but only if it is correct operatively.
Considerig the ground level autofunction for the harmonic oscillator:
$$\phi_0(x)=\left( \frac{m\omega}{\pi \hbar} \right)^{\frac{1}{4}}\exp\left[ -\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}x^2 \right]$$
I derived that
$$\phi_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}(a^{\dagger})^n\phi_0(x)$$
Considering that
$$a^{\dagger}=\sqrt{\frac{\omega m }{2 \hbar}}\left (x-\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\frac{d}{dx} \right)$$
It' s true that for example:
$$(a^{\dagger})^3= \left( \frac{\omega m }{2 \hbar}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} \left (x^3-3x^2\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\frac{d}{dx}+3x\left(\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\right)^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2} +\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's almost correct, but not quite. Imagine $(a^\dagger)^2$ is actually acting on a wavefunction (say, $\psi$). Then
\begin{align} (a^\dagger)^2 \psi & = \left( \frac{\omega m}{2 \hbar}\right) \left( x - \frac{\hbar}{m \omega}\frac{d}{dx} \right)\left( x - \frac{\hbar}{m \omega}\frac{d}{dx} \right)\psi
\\ & = \left( \frac{\omega m}{2 \hbar}\right) \left( x^2 \psi-\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\frac{d}{dx}(x\psi )-\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}x\frac{d\psi}{dx}+\left( \frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\right)^2\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} \right)
\\ &= \left( \frac{\omega m}{2 \hbar}\right) \left( \left(x^2 -\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\right)\psi-2\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}x\frac{d\psi}{dx}+\left( \frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\right)^2\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} \right)
\end{align}
The key point is that the $d/dx$ sits outside of the $x$ in the second term in the second line.

Comment: You're completely right, I'm a fool because I knew they were not commuting but I did not think you can write $2AB$ just because they commute.

Answer (score 3):

**Not correct.** $x$ and $\frac{d}{dx}$ do not commute. Try to explicitly apply the $a^{\dagger}$ operator twice on some function.